# VBA Runtime Error 1004 on Set chartObject = myWS.Chartobjects.Add(0,0,100,100)

Tags: vba, excel

I came across a problem in my VBA code. What I am trying to do is create a chartObject, add a chart to my worksheet and paste an image into it.

My Code so far is as follows:

```
Function RangeToImage(sheetName As String, rangeToBeExported As String)

    Dim exportRange As Range
    Dim fName As String: fName = sheetName & getConstNameForRange(rangeToBeExported)
    Dim cObject As ChartObject 'ChartObject
    Dim myChart As Chart
    Dim myWB As Workbook, myWS As Worksheet

    Set myWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set myWS = myWB.Worksheets(sheetName)

    myWS.Activate
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

    Call goToThisRange(myWS.Cells(1, 1))

    Set exportRange = Worksheets(sheetName).Range(rangeToBeExported)
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    exportRange.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    Set cObject = myWS.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, 100, 100)
    cObject.Width = exportRange.Width
    cObject.Height = exportRange.Height
    cObject.Activate

    Set myChart = cObject.Chart
    myChart.Paste
    myChart.Export getSpeicherort(fName) & IMAGEFORMATEXT, IMAGEFORMAT
    myChart.Parent.Delete

End Function
```

However, the line

```
Set cObject = myWS.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, 100, 100)
```

throws

> Runtime Error 1004: Application-defined or Object-defined error

I'm completely lost with this one, is there anything I am missing or misunderstanding here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll get that error if the sheet is protected

Comment: I ran a simplified version of your code and it worked fine giving no error at all, so I don't think that line of code is the problem. I then protected the sheet, as per Tim Williams' suggestion, and got your same error on that line of code.

Comment: Set myWS = myWB.Worksheets(belegIdString) :    you did not defined belegIdString

Comment: @Dy.Lee I forgot to change that variable before posting the code. It should be "sheetName". Will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @TonyM I forgot to add the lines myWS.Unprotect and myWS.Protect. I'll post this as the answer to my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments of @TimWilliams and @TonyM my code works now. The Runtime Error 1004 was thrown because the sheet was still protected.

So I added

```
myWS.Unprotect
```

and

```
myWS.Protect
```

to the following code:

```
Function RangeToImage(sheetName As String, rangeToBeExported As String)

    Dim exportRange As Range
    Dim fName As String: fName = sheetName & getConstNameForRange(rangeToBeExported)
    Dim cObject As ChartObject 'ChartObject
    Dim myChart As Chart
    Dim myWB As Workbook, myWS As Worksheet

    Set myWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set myWS = myWB.Worksheets(sheetName)

    myWS.Unprotect

    myWS.Activate
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False

    Call goToThisRange(myWS.Cells(1, 1))

    Set exportRange = Worksheets(sheetName).Range(rangeToBeExported)
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    exportRange.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    Set cObject = myWS.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, 100, 100)
    cObject.Width = exportRange.Width
    cObject.Height = exportRange.Height
    cObject.Activate

    Set myChart = cObject.Chart
    myChart.Paste
    myChart.Export getSpeicherort(fName) & IMAGEFORMATEXT, IMAGEFORMAT
    myChart.Parent.Delete

    myWS.Protect    

End Function
```